# Importing jQuery mobile app into eclipse

Tags: android, jquery, eclipse, web-applications

hi¡¡¡ wish you can help me with this problem¡¡¡ thanks in advance.

I've made a project in a drag-and-drop builder for
creating cross-platform mobile apps and websites, and now, i want to make an app native, apk extension, in order to take it into Android Market. After finish the project, i receive a source code bundle for Eclipse (phonegap project).

The link to the phonegap project is this http://www.mediafire.com/download/i3keb345k8y51lh/codiqa-android-f6e7a438-1377719055.zip

Everything works really fine in the project, but when i make the apk archive.......... is not so fine.

Let me explain you, step by step what i am doing, maybe you can tell me if something's wrong and how i can fix it.

Step 1: I export my project as phonegap project (android). I receive a *zip, and i unzip it in my computer .

Step 2: I open Eclipse program and create a "android project from existing code" (file>new>project>android project from existing code")

Step 3: I select the root directory where i've unzipped my codiqa project, and click finish.

Step 4: I export the project as an Android aplication (right button>export>export android application), follow the steps, and i get my application. (In the Manifest, i change debuggable to false.)

Step 5: I install it in my phone, and now come the problems.

Problem 1: I can not open anything from my app. For example, when you normally open a file o website in your phone, you can receive the standard "what program do you wish to use", but not in my app.

Another example, i have a mediafire link in the app in order to download an archive,.......... no matter how many times i press the download button, never work, never download.

Hope you can tell what's wrong and how to fix it, THANKS¡¡¡

Answer (score 1):

You might need to try different platforms.
Sigma Mobility http://sigmamobility.com/ allows building mobile apps using jQuery for free through drag and drop feature, it also allows one to attach Java scripts and CSS styles.

you can through app preview download the source code , and to get cordova project source, you might contact SigmaMobility support for the same.